# Enable show differences in line separators in a diff with Intellij IDEA 13

Tags: intellij-idea, diff, newline

I'm using IDEA 13.0.1. A unit test is failing because of some line separator stuff. But when I try to compare the two results, IDEA says "Contents have differences only in line separators".

And I can't find a setting where I can say show me these differences. Is there one?

Comment: Are you comparing the results with ctrl-D, or how? There might be an option "Ignore whitespace:" that you can adjust.

Comment: I'm running the unit test. This fails and then I click on 'show differences' in the console output.

Comment: Oh ok. Is it failing on an assertEquals? Maybe you can normalize themline separators on the assertEquals arguments some how

Comment: I just want that IDEA is showing me the difference, so I can see where the line separators differ. Eclipse does it...

Comment: by "the difference", is it a difference due to `assertEquals`, or something else?

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same issue, I couldn't find a way to show the difference by clicking show differences, but if you put a break point and look at the strings, they have the line separator written out. For me one string had \n and one had \r\n. \r is also a possible line separator.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem recently. I found a workaround for it, is not that pretty but did the job:

```
yourString.replaceAll("\n", "").replaceAll("\r", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is in what @user1633977 said.

To solve this problem, always use System.lineSeparator() to create your separators. That way they will always be the same and will be OS-independant.

(Remember that different OS can use different symbols as line separators).